# Webextensions - is downloading an image from canvas possible in a background script?

Tags: javascript, canvas, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm working on a firefox extension that allows me to download an image in a different scaling. Currently my script looks like this:

image-resize-download.js:

```
var size = 500;

browser.menus.create({
    id: "dl-resized",
    title: 'Download Resized',
    contexts: ["image"]
});

browser.menus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
    if (info.menuItemId == "dl-resized") {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var cc = canvas.getContext("2d");
        canvas.width = size;
        canvas.height = size;
        var img = new Image();
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);

        img.onload = function () {
            var canvas2 = document.createElement('canvas'),
                cc2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');

            canvas2.width = img.width * 0.5;
            canvas2.height = img.height * 0.5;
            cc2.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height);
            cc.drawImage(canvas2, 0, 0, canvas2.width * 0.5, canvas2.height * 0.5,
                0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
                browser.downloads.download({
                    url : URL.createObjectURL(blob),
                    filename: 'file.jpg'
                });
                document.body.removeChild(canvas);
            }, 'image/jpeg');
        };
        img.src = info.srcUrl;
    }
});
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "ImageResizeDownload",
  "description": "Downloads image in different sizes.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["image-resize-download.js"]
  },

  "permissions": [
    "menus",
    "downloads"
  ]
}
```

The problem is that the background script seemingly isn't able to create a blob of the canvas, crashing instead. I already tried to apply a html page including the script as background page already, which also didn't work. When I implement the listener function in a content-script instead, the blob function works fine, but the script lacks the necessary permissions for the API.

Is there a way I can make the background script prompt a download with the canvas content? Or do I have to resort on an additional content-script that communicates with the background one?

Comment: Have you tried changing `"background": {
    "scripts": ["image-resize-download.js"]
  }` to `"background": {
    "page": ["image-resize.html"]
  }` then refering to the js there. You are trying to append a canvas to the body, but you haven't defined any body

Comment: That's what I said I already tried, but it doesn't work. When I watch Firefox' debugging inspector, there's an existing body, and it can even append the canvas to it. The script fails once it tries to generate the blob though.

Comment: Just curious, does it say browser isn't responding in the background page when you try to generate it?

Comment: Nope, nothing like that.

Comment: try `const downloading = browser.downloads.download(...);`

`downloading.then(function(result) { console.log(result);},function(error){console.log(error); })`

Comment: No effect, as the blob function itself won't run. I added console logs before the download, they won't get reached.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `"<all_urls>"` [permission](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns#%3Call_urls%3E) to your `manifest.json`.

I was getting a DOM security error when I tried to use canvas in a Firefox extension. Adding that permission fixed the issue for me. I tried it after reading through this [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1318565), where someone mentioned `"<all_urls>"`.